# Trying to calculate 5 simultanious equations in Mathematica

Tags: algebra-precalculus, systems-of-equations, mathematica

$\def\1{x_1}\def\2{x_2}\def\3{x_3}\def\f{f(\1,\2,\3)}\def\bs{\bigskip}\def\b{\begin{pmatrix}}\def\e{ \end{pmatrix}}\def\le{\left}\def\ri{\right}\def\g{g(\1,\2,\3)}\def\l{\lambda}\def\n{\nabla}\def\x{\lambda_1}\def\y{\lambda_2}$

I am putting in the following input:

> Solve[{2 + 2 a*d + 2 a*e == 0, 1 - 2 b + 2 d*b + 2 e*b == 0, 
>     1 + 2 d*c + 2 e*c == 0, -2 + a^2 - 2 b + b^2 + c^2 == 
>      0, -2 + a^2 + b^2 + c^2 == 0}, {a, b, c, d, e}]

and it is returning:
Output[10]= {}

What am I doing wrong? Is this not computable?

$$

\begin{equation} 2+2\x\1+2\y\1 = 0%8
\end{equation}

\begin{equation} 1+2\x\2+2\y\2-2\y = 0%9
\end{equation}

\begin{equation} 1+2\x\3+2\y\3=0%10
\end{equation}

\begin{equation} \1^2 + \2^2 - 2\2+\3^2-2=0 %11
\end{equation}

\begin{equation} \1^2 + \2^2 + \3^2 - 2 = 0%12
\end{equation}$$

Comment: The Mathematica equations you entered do not correspond to the system of equations. In the Mathematica equations, you seem to use $b$ for $x_2$, but the second equation then reads $1-2x_2+2\lambda_1x_2+2\lambda_2x_2=0$, which is not the same as what you typed below.

Comment: Not a solution, but probably quickly reduce the system through some simple observations. Combining the last two equations by subtracting left- and right-hand sides gives $x_2 = 0$, substituting this in the equation gives $\lambda_2 = \frac{1}{2}$.

Comment: Solving the second system of equations gives $\lambda_1=-1,\lambda_2= \frac{1}{2},x_1=1,x_2=0,x_3=1$.

Comment: Answered amazingly here, thanks guys. http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/58054/trying-to-solve-simultaneous-equations-based-on-format-found-on-official-website/58056?noredirect=1#comment166342_58056

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the notations of your Mathematica command, you should notice that variables $a,b,c$ can be eliminated using the first three equations. This leads to $$a=\frac{-1}{d+e}$$ $$b=-\frac{1}{2 (d+e-1)}$$ $$c=\frac{1}{2 (d+e)}$$ Now, replacing these in the next equations, the fourth becomes $$ \frac{5}{4 (d+e)^2}+\frac{1}{d+e-1}+\frac{1}{4 (d+e-1)^2}-2=0$$ and the fifth becomes $$\frac{5}{(d+e)^2}+\frac{1}{(d+e-1)^2}-8=0$$ So, only $(d+e)$ terms everywhere and then the problem.